# How to return array of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, return

I have function:

```
int read_file() {
  ifstream file("plik");
  if(!file.is_open()) {
    throw -1;
  }
  int i = 0;
  string line[MAXSIZE];
  while(getline(plik, line[i])) {
    cout<<line[i]<<endl;
    i++;
  }

  return i; 
}
```

But i want to return array of strings:

`line[]`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't. Arrays are not copyable.

Use a `std::vector<std::string>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you really, really wanted to, you could dynamically allocate an array and return a pointer to that array:

```
std::string* getArray() 
{
  return (new std::string[10]);
}
```

BUT you then need to cater for freeing up the memory you allocated using `delete[]` to avoid a memory leak.

Ask yourself:

- Which bit of your code should be responsible for doing this?
- Will you remember that that pointer represents a dynamically-allocated array later on, elsewhere in your code?
- What happens if you pass that pointer around your program and accidentally use it somewhere after another bit of code has called `delete[]` on it? (Segmentation fault is the answer).
- If you pass a pointer to an array around, how does the code that uses that pointer know the size of your array? `std::vector` keeps count of the items for you, so no problem there.

That's why using an `std::vector<std::string>` is a better idea. Returning a pointer to a dynamically allocated array introduces all sorts of problems that are better avoided than solved.

Comment: Another tough question raised by the example and solved by `vector`: How does the calling function know how many elements are in the array?

Comment: @thefourtheye Sure, better than returning a naked pointer to an array, but worse than using a container like vector which gives you an api to manage the data. See aschepler's point above.

Answer (score 3):

Standard 8.3.5p6:

> Functions shall not have a return type of type array or function, although they may have a return type of type pointer or reference to such things.

As @Tomalak hinted, Just Say No to arrays.  They're related to all sorts of gotchas that you can usually avoid if you can use a `vector` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise against returning an `std::vector<std::string>` as well. Instead, I'd pass an iterator, and have the function write the data to wherever the iterator points. This way, the function can equally well write the data to a vector, or a deque, or (if you want) directly to an output stream.

Using that, your function borders on trivial:

```
// I've changed the definition slightly, to let you pass it a filename instead
// of hard-coding one.
//
template <class outIt>
void read_file(std::string const &filename, outIt output) { 
     std::ifstream in(filename);
     std::string line;

     while (std::getline(in, line))
         *output++ = line;
}
```

To use this to copy the data to standard output, roughly as in the question, you'd do something like:

```
read_file("plik", std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: +1 - I like your answer better than mine, as it avoids the (comparatively) expensive copy.